# How to move Jupyter notebook cells up/down using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

Anyone knows keyboard shortcut to move cells up or down in Jupyter notebook?
Cannot find the shortcut, any clues?

Comment: For Jupyter Lab you can edit config files in Settings \ Advanced Settings Editor \ Keyboard Shortcuts. Two commands are relevant: `notebook:move-cell-up` and `notebook:move-cell-down`. Instruction is in the default config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Further to honeybadger's response, you can see when you open up the Edit Command Mode shortcuts dialog box that there are no shortcuts defined for moving a cell up and down, by default:

[image: screenshot]

I simply typed in my preferred combination Ctrl-Shift-Down and Ctrl-Shift-Up in the 'add shortcut' field, and pressed Enter. This is the same in Windows/Mac.

Cheers!

Answer (score 29):

The following solution works on JupyterLab (I currently have version 2.2.6):

You must first open the Keyboard Shortcuts configuration file. In JupyterLab you can find it in `Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor` then selecting the "Keyboard Shortcuts" option in the left panel and then editing the "User Preferences" tab at the right.

Expanding on sherdim's answer, you must add two json objects (one for each direction) within the "shortcuts" json array. Here I have chosen the shortcuts `Ctrl + Shift + ↓` and `Ctrl + Shift + ↑`.

```
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            <<other items you may have>>
        },
        {
            "command": "notebook:move-cell-up",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Shift ArrowUp"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        },
        {
            "command": "notebook:move-cell-down",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Shift ArrowDown"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        },
    ]
}
```

Finally, press `Ctrl + S` to save changes.

Now, when you are in the command mode, you should be able to move one or more selected cells up or down. The shortcuts will even appear in the menu `Edit -> Move Cells Up` and `Edit -> Move Cells Down`.

Comment: This was an easy solution to the general problem, thank you

Comment: That works! I wonder why this is not a system default in Jupyter...

Comment: I face this problem in VScode, does VScode have `Advanced Settings Editor`?

Answer (score 6):

David's answer above was helpful, but didn't work for me in Firefox on Xubuntu. I had to make the following change for the selector:

```
{
    "shortcuts": [            

{
            "command": "notebook:move-cell-up",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Alt Shift ArrowUp"
            ],
            "selector": "body"
        },
        {
            "command": "notebook:move-cell-down",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Alt Shift ArrowDown"
            ],
            "selector": "body"
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Same issue here Firefox on Mac OS. This solution worked for me .Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 4):

This is from the [official Jupyter Notebook documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CStarting%20with%20Jupyter%20Notebook%205.0,of%20adding%20custom%20keyboard%20shortcuts.) -

> Starting with Jupyter Notebook 5.0, you can customize the command mode
> shortcuts from within the Notebook Application itself. n”, “n”, “Head
> to the `Help` menu and select the `Edit keyboard Shortcuts` item.n”,
> “A dialog will guide you through the process of adding custom keyboard
> shortcuts.n”, “n”, “Keyboard shortcut set from within the Notebook
> Application will be persisted to your configuration file. n”, “A
> single action may have several shortcuts attached to it

Answer (score 2):

Steps to add a shortcut to move cells up or down

1. Open any Jupyter Notebook
2. click on Help
3. Click on Edit Keyboard Shortcuts
4. Find move cell down and tap on 'add a shortcut', give any shortcut like "D" for example
5. Click on the '+' icon
6. Do the same for move cell up, you can give "U" for this
7. click on Ok
   Now use these shortcuts to move your cells above or below

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS + Chrome:

In the Jupyter menu, click: View -> "Activate Command Palette"

Then search for "Move" -- you'll see the relevant command shortcut. For my unmodified install of Jupyter this is:

- Move up: ctl + shift + up-arrow
- Move down: ctl + shift + down-arrow

Answer (score -3):

`Tab + arrow keys` works for me in Windows.